# WebAuthenticationBroker.authenticateAndContinue after authentication app is not activated

Tags: javascript, html, windows, windows-phone-8.1, winjs

Am trying facebook,twitter,google login using WebAuthenticationBroker.authenticateAndContinue it shows the authentication page when authentication completes the activated event is not triggered and app crashes and am not able to get the crash report.It works fine when debugging the activation event gets triggered but once the app is launched directly it gets crash.

Answer (score 0):

Do you set the callbackUri ? if not, the callback uri is generated by Windows and it's look like at ms-app:// and maybe it's  not supported by this services.